How does composer resolve package names that are not fully qualified as "webapp" or "profiler"?
When you go to a Symfony project (for example created with composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"7.0.*" .) and you run composer require webapp, it will install symfony/webapp-pack.
How does composer find the package name symfony/webapp-pack when it has only been given the string webapp?

All packages are registered in a registry. That is called by composer require. https://packagist.org/

@MarkusZeller I don't get what you're saying.

Go to https://packagist.org/ and search for webapp. See the first result? That is what composer finds.

@MarkusZeller Sooo, you're saying that composer's ability to find the correct package depends on the order that the packagist search engine scores its results? How does it score the results anyway?

Exactly. That's how it works. packagist.org is composers repository. As there is only one match, there is no need for a priotity. webapp-meta is Abandoned! so need to display it. If there are multiple results, you will get a list to choose from.

There are multiple matches. If you do composer require webapp outside a Symfony app, you'll be prompted to choose one. If you do it inside a Symfony app, you'll get symfony/webapp-pack with no prompt. OP is asking, how does it know which?

Symfony uses their own Composer plugin called Flex. It hooks into the require process.
\Symfony\Flex\PackageResolver::resolvePackageName() calls:
\Symfony\Flex\Downloader::getAliases() which makes an HTTP hit to:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/recipes/flex/main/index.json
which contains a JSON-encoded list of Symfony-specific composer aliases:
    "web-server": "symfony/web-server-bundle",
    "web-server-bundle": "symfony/web-server-bundle",
    "webapp": "symfony/webapp-pack",
    "webhook": "symfony/webhook",
    "weblink": "symfony/web-link",

Note this is not limited to just Symfony packages. For example, also in that file:
"alice": "hautelook/alice-bundle",

So, you can do:
composer require alice

